Flutter not displaying network images on web after deploying it online through Github | yet all network images are rendered in debugging mode
I developed a Flutter mobile app using Firebase, and now I've adapted it for the web. After uploading the required web folder to GitHub and deploying the app online using GitHub Pages, I encountered an issue where network images were not displayed. However, everything works fine in debug mode.
I tried building a web using Flutter build
flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit

and
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release  

but unfortunately, neither solution worked.
